# print the block of text after the matched string

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to print the block of the text between two `@@@`, to specify the block I am providing either `foo_bar` or `hey_there` as an identifier:

```
foo_bar
@@@
hey there
how are you
@@@

hey_there
@@@
Hello
howdy
@@@
```

I know simple `/foo_bar/,/@@@/` construct is not going to help, as it will print till the 1st `@@@`, tried few other stuff but non helped.

```
awk '/foo_bar/{if($0 !~ /^@@@$/){print $0;getline}}'
foo_bar
awk '{if($0 ~ /foo_bar/){print $0};if($0 !~ /^@@@$/){print $0;getline}}'
foo_bar
foo_bar
hey there

Hello
```

**Expected output(with or without `@@@`):**

when `foo_bar` is provided print:

```
@@@
hey there
how are you
@@@
```

When `hey_there` is provided:

```
@@@
Hello
howdy
@@@
```

Comment: Can there be a blank line between any pair of `@@@` lines? Can `foo @@@ bar` appear between any pair of blank lines? Can `foo_bar` appear between any pair of blank lines (e.g. could `hey there` in the first block actually be `hey_there`)? When searching for `foo_bar` as the title, if `foo_bar_etc` exists as a title should it's block be printed too?

Comment: no, leading spaces are by mistake. Thanks.

Comment: If there shouldn't be leading spaces in your example then [edit] your question to fix your example, don't just say "they're a mistake" in a comment and not correct the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
awk -v RS= -v s='foo_bar' '$1 == s && match($0, /@@@.*@@@/) {
print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' file

@@@
hey there
how are you
@@@

# and this one

awk -v RS= -v s='hey_there' '$1 == s && match($0, /@@@.*@@@/) {
print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' file

@@@
Hello
howdy
@@@
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk to use a regex as the record separator:

```
$ gawk 'f; {f=(NR%2 && $0==s)}' RS='\n@@@\n+' s=hey_there file
Hello
howdy
```

change `f;` to `f {print;exit}` if you want to quit after printing the first match. Use `f && RT` if you need to ensure that a closing "\n@@@\n" is present.

Answer (score 1):

With any awk, without relying on blank line separation between sections:

```
$ awk -v s=hey_there '$0=="@@@"{p=!p;next} !p {f=($0==s)} p&&f' file
Hello
howdy
```

`p` is switched on/off for each "@@@" line. If `p` is off, `f` is set based on the comparison of the current line with `s`. When both `p` and `f` are "on", lines can be printed. No check is made for the presence of a closing "@@@" line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;/foo_bar/{n;/@@@/!ba;p;:b;n;p;//!bb}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing (`-n`) as this is a filtering solution.

Match on `foo_bar` then fetch the next line.

If that line contains `@@@`, print it and any further lines until another line containing `@@@`.

N.B. If the line following a match on `foo_bar` does not contain `@@@` it may contain `foo_bar`.

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available/acceptable. Using relative line/buffer address. `-` and `+`

```
printf '%s\n' "/foo_bar/+1;/@@@/p" | ed -s file.txt
```

Output.

```
@@@
hey there
how are you
@@@
```

---

```
printf '%s\n' "/hey_there/+1;/@@@/p" | ed -s file.txt
```

Output

```
@@@
Hello
howdy
@@@
```